# Is there a resource that compares travel insurances?

Tags: online-resources, insurance

Is there an online resource that compares travel insurances.

I am particulary interested in flight (cancelation, delays, etc), health aspects and of course overall value for money.

Answer (score 2):

The answer strongly depends on your country of residence, because usually insurance policies are limited to residents. There are a couple resources in the UK, my favourite is:
http://www.moneysavingexpert.com/insurance/cheap-travel-insurance